# shortcut keys for shutdown, sleep and restart for mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using mac laptop first time and I habituated with windows shortcuts.
So tried to find the shortcuts for mac too but didn't got.
So anyone please tell me What are the shortcut keys for shutdown, sleep and restart for mac-airbook laptops.[This is my laptop keyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt5Tp.jpg)

Please suggest the shortcut keys for above keyboard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

> 1) **shift + control + power button = sleep mode**
>
> 2) **control + power button = show all three options** shutdown, sleep and 
>      restart in a popup

But I didn't got that why people are giving negative votes for the question??
Is the question is wrong or the person giving that negative vote is too intelligent, that's why he/she felt this is a stupid question.